# how can I Fix below error any one please suggest me

Tags: node.js, express

(node:3088) DeprecationWarning: Using Buffer without `new` will soon stop working. Use `new Buffer()`, or preferably `Buffer.from()`, `Buffer.allocUnsafe()` or
`Buffer.alloc()` instead.

Comment: which version of node.js you are using ? Can you show your code

Answer (score 0):

This warning message looks you are using node version greater/equal to 6.0.0 and not instating Buffer with new keyword . Its deprecated from 6 version onward

[check document](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_new_buffer_size)

```
const buf1 = new Buffer('buffer');
```